# I cant find the error in the code it always shows "error": "('count', None) whenever i tried to test it in postman

Tags: python, recommendation-engine, supabase

I am creating a content-based algorithm in python. I will use it to angular to make a recommendation, but every time I test it in postman it show

```
{
    "error": "('count', None)"
}
```

Here's the code that I used. There's no problem with the connection with the supabase since I already check it and use debugger

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from supabase import create_client
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import linear_kernel

app = Flask(__name__)


supabase_url = 'this_is_for_url' 
supabase_key = 'this_is_for_key'
supabase = create_client(supabase_url, supabase_key)

# Function to get recommendations based on clinic features
def get_recommendations(selected_clinic, df, cosine_sim):
    # Get the index of the selected clinic
    idx = df[df['cName'] == selected_clinic].index[0]

    # Get the pairwise similarity scores of all clinics with that clinic
    sim_scores = list(enumerate(cosine_sim[idx]))

    # Sort the clinics based on the similarity scores
    sim_scores = sorted(sim_scores, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

    # Get the scores of all similar clinics
    sim_scores = sim_scores[1:2]

    # Get the clinic indices
    clinic_indices = [i[0] for i in sim_scores]

    # Return the similar clinics
    return df['cName'].iloc[clinic_indices].tolist()

# Custom tokenizer function
def custom_tokenizer(text):
    return text.split()

@app.route('/api/recommendations', methods=['POST'])
def recommend():
    try:
        # Fetch data from Supabase
        response, error = supabase.from_('clinic_tbl').select('*').execute()

        # Check for errors or empty data
        if error:
            return jsonify({'error': str(error)})

        if not response['data']:
            return jsonify({'error': 'No clinics available'})

        # Convert the Supabase response to a Pandas DataFrame
        data = {
            'cName': [],
            'cService': [],
            'cHealthcare': [],
            'cSchedule': [],
        }

        for row in response['data']:
            data['cName'].append(row.get('cName', ''))
            data['cService'].append(row.get('cService', ''))
            data['cHealthcare'].append(row.get('cHealthcare', ''))
            data['cSchedule'].append(row.get('cSchedule', ''))

        df = pd.DataFrame(data)

        # Check if the DataFrame is empty
        if df.empty:
            return jsonify({'error': 'No clinics available'})

        # Combine text features into a single string
        df['content'] = df['cService'] + ' ' + df['cHealthcare'] + ' ' + df['cSchedule']

        # Create a TF-IDF vectorizer with custom tokenizer
        tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=custom_tokenizer, stop_words='english')

        # Fit and transform the content into TF-IDF vectors
        tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(df['content'])

        # Check if the vocabulary is not empty
        if len(tfidf_vectorizer.vocabulary_) == 0:
            return jsonify({'error': 'Empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only contain stop words'})

        # Calculate the cosine similarity between documents
        cosine_sim = linear_kernel(tfidf_matrix, tfidf_matrix)

        # Get the selected clinic name from the request
        selected_clinic_name = request.json.get('clinic_name', '')

        # Get recommendations for the selected clinic
        recommendations = get_recommendations(selected_clinic_name, df, cosine_sim)

        return jsonify({'recommendations': recommendations})

    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({'error': str(e)})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When I try to test it using csv file it doesn't encounter any error and shows the recommendation using postman.The code works. Here is the code

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import linear_kernel

app = Flask(__name__)

# Function to get recommendations based on clinic features
def get_recommendations(selected_clinic, df, cosine_sim):
    # Get the index of the selected clinic
    idx = df[df['cName'] == selected_clinic].index[0]

    # Get the pairwise similarity scores of all clinics with that clinic
    sim_scores = list(enumerate(cosine_sim[idx]))

    # Sort the clinics based on the similarity scores
    sim_scores = sorted(sim_scores, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

    # Get the scores of all similar clinics
    sim_scores = sim_scores[1:2]

    # Get the clinic indices
    clinic_indices = [i[0] for i in sim_scores]

    # Return the similar clinics
    return df['cName'].iloc[clinic_indices].tolist()

# Custom tokenizer function
def custom_tokenizer(text):
    return text.split()

@app.route('/api/recommendations', methods=['POST'])
def recommend():
    try:
        # Load clinic data from CSV file
        df = pd.read_csv('clinic_tbl.csv')

        # Check for missing values
        if df.isnull().values.any():
            return jsonify({'error': 'Missing values in the dataset'})

        # Check if the DataFrame is empty
        if df.empty:
            return jsonify({'error': 'No clinics available'})

        # Combine text features into a single string
        df['content'] =  df['cService'] + ' ' + df['cHealthcare'] + ' ' + df['cSchedule']

        # Create a TF-IDF vectorizer with custom tokenizer
        tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=custom_tokenizer, stop_words='english')

        # Fit and transform the content into TF-IDF vectors
        tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(df['content'])

        # Check if the vocabulary is not empty
        if len(tfidf_vectorizer.vocabulary_) == 0:
            return jsonify({'error': 'Empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only contain stop words'})

        # Calculate the cosine similarity between documents
        cosine_sim = linear_kernel(tfidf_matrix, tfidf_matrix)

        # Get the selected clinic name from the request
        selected_clinic_name = request.json.get('clinic_name', '')

        # Get recommendations for the selected clinic
        recommendations = get_recommendations(selected_clinic_name, df, cosine_sim)

        return jsonify({'recommendations': recommendations})

    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({'error': str(e)})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

can you help me find the problem with the first code

I want to fix the error issue

Comment: Does your table in supabase have row level security (RLS) enabled? as this could result in you not getting any data back. Can you do a print in your code on the response from this line `response, error = supabase.from_('clinic_tbl').select('*').execute()` to see if there are any results.